# Difficulty properly joining tables in Laravel query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm having difficulty properly joining tables in L9. This joins my products and additionalProducts tables. The mission is to get all the products that can be added with productId(x). I have the Product table with all the info and additonalProduct that look like this:

| id | product_id | additionalProductId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 5 |

The meaning for product_id=1 I want to get all the info of the products with id 2 and 4 from 'product' table and for product_id=2 get the info of products 3 and 5.

This query is working when productId is hard coded('1' or '2')
but when I tray make it dynamic for some reason I got error $productId undefined.

`$productId = $productsInfo[0]->product_id;`
(when i print it with dd it show id=1 or 2).
but inside the query it is undefined and I cannot understand why and how to fix it.

```
$viewData['additionalProducts'] = DB::table('products as p')
    ->join('addtionalproducts as ap', function ($join) {
        $join->on('p.id', '=', 'ap.additionalProductId')
             ->select('p*')
             ->where('ap.product_id', '=', $productId);
    })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're joining the wrong columns:

```
$join->on('p.id', '=', 'ap.additionalProductId')
```

And I don't really understand this part either, because the `WHERE` clause doesn't belong there:

```
->select('p*')->where('ap.product_id', '=', $productId);
```

Which should rather be:

```
$join->on('p.additionalProductId', '=', 'ap.product_id')
```

And watch out for spelling errors; the question had quite few before the edit.
Better first try without the `WHERE` clause to get any results, then start to limit.

A join doesn't need any sub-query, that why it's actually as simple as that:

```
DB::table('products')
    ->leftJoin('addtionalproducts', 'products.additionalProductId', '=', 'addtionalproducts.product_id')
    ->where('products.product_id', '=', $productId);
    ->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#joins

Comment: It is query inside other query it works well when i tray hardcoded   `$viewData['additionalProducts'] = DB::table('products as p')
            ->join('addtionalproducts as ap', function ($join) {
                $join->on('p.id', '=', 'ap.additionalProductId')->select('p*')
                    ->where('ap.product_id', '=', '1');})
            ->get();  `

Comment: There is no difference to the code above, except the `'1'`, which may be unknown within that scope and it joins the wrong columns (don't call this "working") - that's exactly why the where clause belongs to the main query, not the join. Write this as a pure SQL query and you'll see where building the SQL query fails.

Comment: the pure sql should look something like this : `
  Select * from products as p join (select * from addtionalproducts where product_id=1) a on .p.id = a.additionalProductId` and this show exactly  the same result

Comment: @Romka That's not how to write the join; see my updated answer. That you get seemingly "correct" results may be due to not having too many IDs and it may only coincidently deliver the expected IDs. Don't use sub-queries unless you have to, which is not the case here.

Comment: yes but I want to get all the products that connected to productId=x ,I cant have  additionalProductId column because 1 product can be connected to multiply products. with sub query first I get all the list of connected products and then I go for each from the list and get all the data of the products ,seems it works well hardcoded I just cant understand why with parametar that defined outside of query it undefined inside the query.

Comment: Reconsider the database design. When such useless complexity is required, it may be sub-optimal. Throwing complexity at such a simple problem only makes it worse, than any better. Despite it may appear as id it's "working", the performance would be poor... as the sub-query runs on every single row of the main query, despite the sub-query is not required at all, when properly joining the tables.